# Inference of the parameters of a linear congruential generator

Tags: r, inference, random-generation, software

Is there an R package or other open source software that solves the problem of inferring the parameters of a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)?
Such inference can be done as e.g. described [here](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf) in a strict sense.

On ther other hand, I would also be interested in statistical methods that can be applied in this context.